# How can I set a cell's language to cython in a Jupyter notebook in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, cython

I'd like to write Cython in vscode using the built-in jupyter notebook and Cython extension. I can actually do it and it will compile just fine, but vscode thinks it's python code and will complain about all kinds of syntax and linting errors. I know I could write in pure python mode, but I'm also trying to learn Cython simultaneously, so that's not very helpful.

I tried installing Cython language extensions, but none of them appeared in vscode when I tried to switch language of cell.

Is this possible? How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not currently supported (at the time of this writing).

See [Closed
Cythonized notebook cells render incorrectly
#11349](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/11349), which is closed pointing toward [Automatically change cell language based on cell magics #4588](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4588), where my understanding is that once those changes are implemented, you'd be able to use a cell magic like `%%cython`, and the cell's language would automatically change to cython. The exact details don't seem 100% fleshed out yet, and the issue doesn't seem to be high priority to the maintainers, though they mention in that thread that they do want to get to implementing this eventually. <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

For your learning purposes / reference, I found this information by googling "`github vscode jupyter issues cython`" and looking through linked GitHub issues.